# How do I set the value of a key in on array as the key in an other array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to get the value `feature_1` of a key `name` from the array `data` and set `feature_1` as the key of another array `asset` which has an array as value.

Example :

```
//input:

data: {
   name: "feature_1",
   value_a: 1,
   value_b: 2
}

//Output:

asset: {
    feature_1:[1,2]
}
```

Comment: Hmm, what's `{1}` and `{2}`? Those aren't valid objects

Comment: sorry, I wrote it wrong it should just be an array of values I changed it, may be it makes more sense now ?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service.  You need to try something, and then if you cannot solve it, we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var asset = {};
if ('name' in data) {
    var tmp = [];
    for (k in data){
        if (k != 'name') tmp.push(data[k]);
    }
    asset[data['name']] = tmp;
}
```

and in case your interpreter supports ES6 you can use, for example:

```
let {name, ...v} = data;
let asset = {[name]: Object.values(v)};
```

Comment: How can i include values which are stored in different objects for the key... exmaple: feature_1 [100,110,120]  would i do something like this...... let asset = {[name]: data.value.item,data.value.item2};.....  Sorry for this question I am still new to JavaScript

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand correctly what do you want to achieve. If you have two objects "data" and "data2", and in each of them there is a key "name" with value "feature_1", then you can do something like: let {name: n1, ...v} = data;    let {name, ...v2} = data2;    let asset = {[name]: Object.values(v).concat(Object.values(v2))};  If you want something different, could you please explain more precisely

Answer (score 0):

If supports same keys in a `JSON` object ( It seems not ) You can do it like this:

```js
let data= {
   name: "feature_1",
   value_a: 1,
   value_b: 2,
   value_x: 500,
   name: "feature_2",
   value_a: 17,
   value_b: 21,
   value_x: 510
}

console.log(
  Object.entries(data).reduce((a,[key,value],index)=>{
    if (key==='name')
      return {index, assets: {...a.assets, [value]:[]}};

    return {
      index : a.index,
      assets : {
        ...a.assets,
        [Object.entries(a.assets)[a.index][0]] : [...Object.entries(a.assets)[a.index][1],value]
      }};
  },{index:0,assets:{}}).assets
);
```

But we know the correct way is using separated array rows.

Answer (score -1):

This can be accomplished the following way:

```js
const obj = {
  data: {
    name: "feature_1",
    value_a: 1,
    value_b: 2
  }
};

const output = {
  assets: {
    [obj.data.name]: Object.values(obj.data).filter(el => el !== obj.data.name)
  }
}

console.log(output);
```